# What was the Donnager's escort doing during the battle?

Tags: the-expanse-2015

The Donnager had one frigate, the Tachi, available. The [Wiki](http://expanse.wikia.com/wiki/The_Expanse_Wiki) says that there were more ships. After the battle in episode 4 of season 1 got serious, why weren't these smaller vessels deployed to help out with the battle? Or were they?

Answer (score 1):

I don't have the episode in front of me right now, but here's an answer from the books.

The *Donnager* was caught off guard. When the Martians intercepted the *Knight*, with our heroes in it, they assumed the ships following her were chasing it. However, they were surprised when the ships took on the *Donnager* itself, and succeeded.

The Martians could have deployed the frigates before the mystery ships came close. Hubris made them believe that wouldn't happen, but they were wrong.

First, the mysterious ships outmaneuvered or destroyed the *Donnager*'s torpedoes. Then, they managed to sneak some torpedoes of their own past the *Donnager*'s point defense cannons. This made the ships able to get close enough for close-quarters battle, at which point it was probably too late to get the frigates into the fight.

Then, the ships surprisingly fired rail gun slugs at the huge ship. (The frigates probably wouldn't have been able to do anything the *Donnager* hadn't already tried, except that they were faster and couldn't be hit by the rail guns.) And then, of course, the ships actually boarded the *Donnager*, at which point the frigates were useless – and the boarders placed half a dozen people in the hangar bay anyway.

Comment: Tachi would not make much difference in CQB. It was not really a match for even a single stealth ship. In the Thoth station battle they barely won even though they were training for that mission, used the station as cover and almost got killed anyway. The stealth however was unprepared, most of the crew probably died from decompression since they weren't wearing vac suits. In the Donnager battle it would be the other way around and it would be quickly killed off.

Comment: I wonder why the remaining 2 stealths (those which deployed the breaching prods) did not chase/fire at the Tachi when it escaped? I'm sure the boarders in the hangar alerted their ships that Tachi is about to bail so those would properly greet it with railgun/PDCs fire. And Tachi had exactly zero chances of survival.